# Close rich:popupPanel on back-end exception

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces

Richfaces 4.5.1
JSF 2.2
WildFly 8.1.0
JDK 1.8

I am using a `a4j:commandButton` to trigger a bean method and show a `rich:popupPanel`:-

```
<a4j:commandButton id="getReportList_btn" value="Get Report List" action="#{service.downloadReportList}" onbegin="#{rich:component('reportList_dlg')}.show()" />
```

Any exception thrown by the `service.downloadReportList` Java code ultimately results in a `FacesMessage` which I am displaying using `rich:notifyMessages`.

If (and only if) an exception occurs in the Java code I want to hide the `rich:popupPanel` without any user interaction, either immediately or after the `rich:notifyMessages` panel is dismissed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@data`, it makes a bean property available in Javascript.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="getReportList_btn"
    value="Get Report List"
    action="#{service.downloadReportList}"
    data="#{service.downloadFailure}"
    onbegin="#{rich:component('reportList_dlg')}.show()"
    oncomplete="if(event.data)#{rich:component('reportList_dlg')}.hide()" />
```

So if an exception occurs during `service.downloadReportList` set `downloadFailure` to true.